# React server side render with nashorn

Tags: nashorn

Is it possible SSR react app with Nashorn? 
It work for single thread. Nashorn render my app in 700-1600ms. Nodejs do it for the same time. BUT - I need ~30 seconds to eval my js app. As I understood I can't share bindings between threads, but eval results is part of the bindings.
 I can't do server side render without eval script for every client. Is it correct? (create pool is bad idea - I don't know how many connections I can have - 1,5,10,20...)